# jQuery addClass/removeClass after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I've got an ajax form submission working well but I'd like to add a "success" class to indicate to the user that the request was completed when the user checked or unchecked a box.  I've tried a few things so far:

```
    $(".box").change(function() {
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = "id=" + id + "&crudtype=myapp";
    var clickedObj = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myphppage",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
          var oldClass = clickedObj.attr("class");
          clickedObj.fadeIn(1400, function() {
            clickedObj.removeClass(oldClass);
            clickedObj.addClass("updated");  
          });
          clickedObj.fadeOut(1400, function() {
            clickedObj.removeClass("updated");  
            clickedObj.addClass(oldClass);
          });
        } 
    });
});
```

That one does indeed apply the "updated" class but the fadeOut actually removes the entire row of data (parent().parent() is the  tag that I'm targeting.)

```
$(".box").change(function() {
  var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = "id=" + id + "&crudtype=myapp";
  var clickedObj = $(this).parent().parent();
  $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: "/myphppage",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function() {
        var oldClass = clickedObj.attr("class");
        clickedObj.removeClass(oldClass);
        clickedObj.addClass("updated", 1000);
        clickedObj.removeClass("updated", 1000);
        clickedObj.addClass("updated");
      } 
  });
});
```

I also tried this, but all that happens is that it (evidently) removes the existing class, adds the new one, and then does the same thing in reverse immediately so the new class is never seen.  It appears that the 1000 delay is ignored despite the fact that I'm running jQueryUI on this site.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

EDIT: Adding in HTML code:

```
<table id="datatable" class="display dataTable" role="grid">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd" role="row">
      <td class="formcell"><input id="actionitem" class="box" type="checkbox" value="1234" name="actionitem[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even" role="row">
      <td class="formcell"><input id="actionitem" class="box" type="checkbox" value="5678" name="actionitem[]"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you also post the HTML?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that -- done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't really know how your fade-effect is supposed to look like. it did make more sense to me to fade out the old class before adding the new one and fading it in. cause you can't see the `<tr>` which is including the checkbox, when it's faded out at the start.
briansol is right with his callbacks and i used `fadeTo` here to prevent `jQuery` from setting `display: none`:

```
$(".box").on("click", function () {
    clickedObj = $(this).parent().parent();

    clickedObj.fadeTo(1400, 0.01, function(){
        clickedObj.removeClass("oldClass").addClass("updated");
        clickedObj.fadeTo(1400, 1.0, function(){
            clickedObj.removeClass("updated").addClass("oldClass");
        });
    });
});
```

i also made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/rmj75wr2/

Comment: Thanks -- I probably wasn't very clear in my original post.  What I'm trying to do is have the selected TR apply a class containing a light green background (whether or not it fades, I don't care), have it remain in effect for a few seconds, and then return to its original class.  I tried your code and it effectively makes the row fade out and then back in again.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out -- I changed the delay to 1 and the opacity to 1.0 for the first fadeTo and I'm in business.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback so that the fadein does its thing and THEN the fadeout event fires.

change

```
      var oldClass = clickedObj.attr("class");
      clickedObj.fadeIn(1400, function() {
        clickedObj.removeClass(oldClass);
        clickedObj.addClass("updated");  
      });
      clickedObj.fadeOut(1400, function() {
        clickedObj.removeClass("updated");  
        clickedObj.addClass(oldClass);
      });
```

to

```
      var oldClass = clickedObj.attr("class");

      clickedObj.removeClass(oldClass).addClass("updated");  

      clickedObj.fadeIn(1400, function() {
        clickedObj.fadeOut(1400, function() {
          clickedObj.removeClass("updated").addClass(oldClass);  //probably unnecessary as its now in a display:none state
      });
```

Comment: Hmm, that seems to do the same thing as my first example: it sets display:none and removes the entire <tr> and all it's contents.  That's what I'm trying to get away from.